pekko: Using throttle with foreachAsync
I want to rate limit something that requires asynchronous processing.
However, when I try to use throttle with a Sink.foreachAsync it doesn't seem to wait for the futures to complete before allowing more items through the throttle.
For example, consider this code:
type Task = () => Future[Any]

val q = Source.queue[Task](4, OverflowStrategy.backpressure, 256)
  .throttle(1, 10.millis, 1, _ => 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
  .to(Sink.foreachAsync(32){ task =>
    println("starting task")
    task().map(v => println(s"got $v"))
  })
  .run()

val p1 = Promise[String]()
val p2 = Promise[String]()
val p3 = Promise[String]()
q.offer(() => p1.future); q.offer(() => p2.future); q.offer(() => p3.future);

It will print three "starting task" messages very quickly, even though none of the futures have actually completed yet.
Is there someway that I can throttle the sink instead of the source?
What I want here is to ensure that the futures in the foreach aren't completed more quickly than the rate (say once per second).
To be more specific, the futures represent http requests to an API that has a rate limit. And I need to comtrol when the requests are actually made, not just when the future is started.

Can you clarify the exact behaviour you want?  Do you want to limit the rate at which tasks start, the rate at which tasks complete, the number of active tasks, or some combination of these three, or something else?

You set parallelism to 10 - the stream could have as much as 10 started futures before it would need to wait with starting the next one.
If your want to proces 1 at a time do
Sink.foreachAsync(1){ ... }


My example is simplified for illustration purposes. The real code has a variable cost, and I want to limit the rate, not the parallelism.

Then you need to modify your code: your queue is correctly throttling - emission of pure values () => Future[Any] which are not executing anything. foreachAsync is correctly running up to 32 Futures in parallel as you told it to. If you want to have 1 running future and parallelize the process then you should rather use something like e.g. .mapAsync.


What I want here is to ensure that the futures in the foreach aren't
completed more quickly than the rate (say once per second).

If the futures take a variable amount of time to run then this is impossible. However careful you are about starting them, there is still a chance that two or more will complete very close to each other, faster than the rate that you set. You can't control when a Future will complete from outside the Future.
If you want to limit the average rate rather than the instantaneous rate then the existing code will work because the average rate of completion will be the same as the average rate of creation.

To be more specific, the futures represent http requests to an API
that has a rate limit. And I need to control when the requests are
actually made, not just when the future is started

If you need to accurately control when an API request is made you must do it at the point that the API call is made. If the call is made inside a Future then this control must be implemented inside the Future not in the code that creates the Future. You can't use pekko streams to control the timing of events that happen inside a Future.
Rather than using streams I suggest that you create a pekko actor that accepts API requests from multiple sources and makes the API calls at the appropriate time. (e.g. by setting a timer when a call is made and waiting for it to time out before making another call).
